# Deriving $pV=RT$ from Joule expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

$\newcommand{\pdifft}[3]{\left(\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}\right)_{#3}}$

I'm going over some past exam papers. One question reads

> Boyle observed that the pressure of an ideal gas varies inversely with its volume at constant temperature. Moreover, the Joule expansion experiment shows that $\pdifft T V U = 0$. Show that these results taken together imply that the equation of state is $pV=RT$, where $R$ is a constant.

So the first part is that $ p = \frac{a}{V}$, where $a$ is some constant/function which may contain $T$. We can use the formula (from $dU=TdS - pdV$)
$$ \pdifft U V T  = T\pdifft p T V - p $$
but by the reciprocal relation 
$$\pdifft U V T  = -\pdifft U T V \underbrace{\pdifft T V U}_{=0} = 0   $$
which combined with first relation implies 
$$ T\pdifft p T V = p $$
but also 
$$ \pdifft p T V  = -\pdifft p V T \pdifft V T p = -\frac{a}{V^2}\pdifft V T p$$
which yields
$$-T\frac{a}{V^2}\pdifft V T p = p.$$

And honestly here I'm stuck. I can't seem to be able to work out the $\pdifft V T p$ based on the information provided... Any hints? Or is this approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It follows from your equation that $$\left(\frac{\partial \ln{p}}{\partial \ln{T}}\right)_V=1$$Integrating this equation yields $$\ln{P}=\ln{T}+\ln{k(V)}$$where $\ln{k(V)}$ is the constant of integration.  Equivalently, $$p=k(V)T$$

The rest is straightforward.